# Alternative for a custom infopath form in sp2010?

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I have a sharepoint 2010 public website for my company. Anonymous access is enabled.  I have a custom list with a custom infopath form. Everything was working fine till yesterday. It dont work anymore. I got this exception on my infopath webpart:

A form template (.xsn) file cannot be accessed. You may not have the required permissions to open the file

I have spend to much time and looking for some alternatives. I would like to have some form with some input fields and a button. After pressing on the button the data will be stored in the list as a new item. It needs to be accesable for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if anonymous have access to **Form Templates**
 library. All Infopath form templates are in this library, so you may want to check if anonymous can access your specific InfoPath too

Comment: I found this "form templates" library only on the top level website. Not in my subsite. Anonymous access is enabled on this library like this: 
Anonymous Users  | Anonymous Users | View Items

Comment: Please help? Im stuck right now..

Comment: see your site as anonymous and go to *Form Templates* library and check if you can see your specific form template

Comment: I see this library only on the top level site. It is empty. I have set this library anonymous accessable to add and view items. My infopath template is published on my custom list. I can see my template in spdesigner under all files -> lists -> myCustomLists -> Item

Comment: As I said, in your top level site, go to **Form Templates** library as anonymous. you should see form templates. if it's empty check this with authenticated user such as System Account.

Comment: I have checked, but it is empty! There are no templates inside this library.

Comment: @KHA if you check *Form Templates* with System Account and there is no template inside that library, then problem is somewhere else and right now I can't think another solution for this problem

Comment: But why are you expecting templates in this library. When I try to publish the form in InfoPath designer the template will save it in the list folder like I describe: under all files -> lists -> myCustomLists -> Item